# Does Southwest Airlines have assigned seating?

Tags: air-travel, seating, southwest-airlines

I have a short flight tonight, from Denver to Oklahoma. I was wondering if anyone has had any experience with Southwest before, and in which do they just allow you to sit wherever a spot is open, or are the seats still chosen for you on the short flight ?

Comment: The possible duplicate is old, I vote to keep this one open (at least till a new update on the answers there.)

Answer (score 5):

As explained in the [Southwest Airlines FAQ](https://www.southwest.com/html/generated/help/faqs/boarding_the_plane_faq.html):

> **Do I have an assigned seat?**
>   Southwest-operated flights have open seating. Once onboard, simply choose any available seat and stow your carryon items in the overhead bin or under the seat in front of you.

Comment: +1. If you're not familiar with Southwest's boarding process, I'd read about it in that link too, because it's a bit unusual and the process of lining up could be confusing.

Comment: @ZachLipton On reading yes it is, but in the airport it is much simpler. I believe the language contributes to the confusion.

Comment: When you check in for your flight you are assigned a position in line. As you board the aircraft you may take any available seat. In practice for most flights this means that if you do not check in online within a few minutes of the 24 hour window opening, you will get your choice of any available middle seat.